# entity framework linq get values except same values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 list type of string below,

**First List :**

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>();
```

**firstList values**

```
10    
15    
33    
45
```

**Second List:**

```
List<string> secondList = new List<string>();
```

**secondList  values**

```
10    
15    
90    
70
```

**Result list must be**

```
10
15
33
45
90
70
```

How can I get matching firstList and secondList after that get only once same values like result in above ?

How can I get same situation for type of **List** ?

Comment: All is in Linq : Union + Distinct

Comment: @Sharped i used Intersect however could not do it myself. İf you have example please share thanks

Comment: `Intersect` only gives you the items they have in common. You want `Union` to get all items from both lists.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Why did you add the asp.net tag? There's nothing web-specific in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) and then Distinct values

```
List<string> thirdList = firstList.Concat(secondList).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
allUniqueItems = first.Union(second).ToList();
```

Comment: `Union` should remove the duplicates, so no need for `Distinct`